# Windows find all files under a directory

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, search, gui, file-search

I'm hoping for the Windows Explorer equivalent to Linux's `find . type -f`.

I did `*.*` in the search field but it listed directories as well; I wanted just files.

Everything I've found on the subject is talking about finding specific file types, I just want files in general. That is, I want the resulting search listing to *consist solely of files of any and all types*, **no directories/folders**.

Comment: is a command feasible? or must it be GUI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I want the resulting search listing to consist solely of files

Use `*.* NOT kind:folder`

Notes:

- `NOT` must be spelled with capital letters.
- Using a filter such as `.**` or `.?` as specified in another answer doesn't work if the location isn't indexed.

**Examples**

No filter:

[image]

`*.* NOT kind:folder` filter:

[image]

---

#### Further Reading

- [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711)

Comment: Per your "Advanced Query Syntax" URL you can make use of boolean operators, so how about `*.* NOT kind:folder`? Essentially the same thing except it excludes folders. Seems to work for me on Windows 10.

Comment: @BrianC Yes, that works. Well spotted. I tried before with `not` not realising it had to be `NOT` :/ Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:** Use `.**` or `.?`

---

I figured this out by randomly trying things :). Just type in `.**`, and voila!

**Edit #1:** I just found out that `.?` works too

[image: explorer]
I'm not really sure why this works, so if anyone figures it out please edit :)

**Edit #2:** I think it has something to do with how `*` matches tons of symbols, and `?` just matches one letter or symbol. But, I'm surprised that `.**` matches `test.c` since it only has one character in the path.

> "the question mark is used to substitute for one letter or symbol that you don't know. The asterisk is used to substitute for many letters and symbols" (http://www.digitalcitizen.life/basics-making-advanced-searches-wildcards-and-filters)

*I'm not really 100% sure why it works, so it might have some unexpected results. But, so far both work for all the files I have tested, including ones with a single character as an extension (test.c)*

Comment: `.**` and `.?` don't work if the location being search is not indexed.

Comment: @DavidPostill It works for me, and I didn't need to index.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe that's a Windows 7 thing.

Comment: @DavidPostill Probably just an issue with the horrible Windows XP search xD

Comment: ? matches one char. Asterisk matches zero or more chars.

Comment: One problem with this: If you have a file with no extension at the end of it, it won't show up.

Comment: doesn't work in Windows 10. It gives me all files and folders. Edit: it seems to work when I tried in an indexed folder